# If I own the DLC on PS3, can I activate it on PC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I own the season pass on PS3, but I'm playing it on PC with my friends who all have season passes on PC. Is there some way I can activate the DLC via linking my PS3 account or anything else?

I just find it pointless to buy the pass twice after I've bought the game twice...

Comment: Unfortunately, the PSN and Steam are 2 completely different systems. You *could* kindly ask Gearbox Software or 2K Games to provide you with a redeemable key for the Steam version of the DLC, but I doubt they'd do it. Well, it certainly wouldn't hurt to try.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not. DLC bought on one platform will remain on this platform. No transfers are possible. Unfortunately if you want to enjoy the full experience on several consoles you'll have to buy the game several times.